# Stopping a jQuery function after modal closes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is repeated every 3 seconds like this:

```
function myFunction() {

// Do something sexy

   var delay = 3000;
   setTimeout(function() {
   myFunction();
   }, delay);

}
```

It's running inside a Bootstrap modal window and it should only run when that window is open.

I tried wrapping the delay into a something like:

```
if ($('#modal-task').hasClass('in')){
    var delay = 3000;
    setTimeout(function() {
    myFunction();
    }, delay);
}
```

But the problem is then if the modal is closed and re-opened, the function runs twice and more times each time it's closed and opened.

How do I kill the function completely when the modal is closed/invisible?

Answer (score 1):

this might work, instead of if statement

```
    function something_sexy () {
    // Do something sexy

       var delay = 3000;
       setTimeout(function() {
       myFunction();
       }, delay);
    }
    while ($('#modal-task').hasClass('in')) {
    something_sexy();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you close the Bootstrap model 'in' will remove from model class. So when close the model clear the timeout It will work.

like.

```
function myFunction() {
// Do something sexy
   console.log("test");
   var delay = 3000;
  //Assign setTimeout in variable timerval 
   let timerval = setTimeout(function() {
   myFunction();
   }, delay);

  //when close the model clear the timeout
   if (!$('.#modal-task').hasClass("in")){
     clearTimeout(timerval );
   }

}
```